# WebActivator is not working with Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, webactivator

I have current version of Orchard CMS 1.6.1 and WebActivator 2.0.1.

Default installation of Orchard. WebActivator PreApplicationStartMethod is not fired.

In the same solution I have sample MVC application and the same WebActivator code works fine.

What is wrong with Orchard app. Is it breaks standard ASP.NET pipeline?

Sample code (I've used both Pre and PostApplicationStartMethod):

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Go2See.Web.App_Start.LocalizationServiceStarter), "PreStart")]
namespace Go2See.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class LocalizationServiceStarter
    {
        public static void PreStart()
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("x");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Orchard does not break standard ASP.NET pipeline (Orchard.Web project is a plain ASP.NET MVC app). WebActivator is an external library, far from being standard. Could you please show a part of the code that is not working? Have you put the correct attributes within Global.asax.cs file?

Comment: Orchard standard app but it uses host initialization and Starter<T>.LaunchStartupThread. I've updated question with code.

Comment: And which attributes within Global.asax.cs file did you mean? There's standard global.asax from Orchard and WebActivator did not use Global.asax.

Comment: I'm investigating this issue for hours now and i tend to give up. It has something to do with `src\Orchard.Web\Web.config`. If you replace it by a standard file `PreStart` will be called. Putting the `PreStart` in a module doesn't work as the modules are loaded dynamically.